# Determinant of an outer product of a vector with itself

Tags: linear-algebra

Given some vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, what is the determinant of the outer product of $v$ with itself? ie. what is:

$$\det (v \cdot v^T)$$

Is there a simple formula for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $ n > 1$, the determinant is Zero because this matrix will have rank $\leq 1$.